# CI modules working on local, but giving 404 not found on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on Codeigniter HMVC & getting an problem that when i execute http://localhost/school_erp/administrator on local it is working fine, but when i access same url on http://mydomain/admnistrator, the it is giving 404 not found.

This line is define in constant
`define('ADMIN_LOGIN_PATH', 'administrator');`

My routes :

```
$route['default_controller']                           = "login/admin";

$route['page/(:any)']                                  = 'page/page/admin/$1';

$route['404_override']                                 = 'error/page/e404';

$route['404']                                          = 'error/page/e404';

$route[ADMIN_LOGIN_PATH]                               = 'login/admin';

$route[ADMIN_LOGIN_PATH.'/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/(:any)']       =  '$1/admin/$2';
```

Plz help..

Comment: Assuming that you put in the URLs verbatim above, it could be because you have a typo of `admnistrator` in your server address, but your local has it spelled correctly `administrator`.

Comment: check you `spelling` and `casing`  Linux is case sensitive filename, windows not so much.

Comment: Please share your .htaccess file.

Comment: .htaccess is present inside application/ folder & it is written "Deny from all" inside it.

Comment: Make sure .htaccess file must be present there and having proper configuration in the server what you installed on any server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that

.htaccess file should be outside the application folder with proper configuration.

The first letter of Controller name should be capital.
eg Login
not login.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database table name case on your remote server is the same as in your code

Because:
"Triggers also correspond to files. Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. This means such names are not case sensitive in Windows, but are case sensitive in most varieties of Unix "

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html