# Codeigniter project not showing desired page when uploaded

Tags: codeigniter, xampp, localhost

I had made a codeigniter project and is working perfectly on XAMPP.

But when I upload the same and modified base_url, and database details and upload it to the live server, its showing 404 Page Not Found Error. What to do???

My .htaccess file inside application contains

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
   Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
   Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180386/ci-modules-working-on-local-but-giving-404-not-found-on-server/45181199#45181199

Comment: Make sure to update .htaccess out side application folder and try the suggested configuration in the answers

Comment: So should I cut that .htaccess file from inside application folder and paste it just outside application(in home directory) @Eiaddar

Comment: And what about the content of .htaccess file. Please help @Eiaddar

Answer (score 0):

Upload your htaccess file
If already uploaded ...
Check rewrite mod on using php info

Thanks

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

few things need to be considered when you moving your project to live server..
1- check Apache server version and write the appropriate .htaccess file 
if you are running in version  2.4.* try this .htaccess config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

else

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

2- check `mod_rewrite` on live servier 
3- check if all required extention such as open_ssl are running in php

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem before. I got these solutions:

1.Configure your .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2.Check your routing.

3.Make sure to **uppercase** the Controllers and Models files..,

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look now. My .htaccess file has different content and is inside application directory